# Only parameterless constructors supported in LINQ and cast to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I know this question has been asked here many times, but none of them address my problem.

I have 2 entities, `StaffDTO` and `Appointment`.
`StaffDTO` has a collection of `Appointment`.
`Appointment` has lazy loaded navigation properties.

```
public class StaffDTO {

    public IEnumerable<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

}

public class Appointment {

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

Now, using LINQ, I built this query:

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
var staff = ctx.Set<Staff>();


var staffs = (from stf in staff
             select new StaffDTO
             {
                 Appointments = stf.StaffAppointments
             }).ToList();
}
```

This works. **BUT**, when I try to serialize `StaffDTO`, I get an error saying the context has been disposed.

This makes sense, because when serializing the object, each `Appointment` in the `StaffDTO.Appointments` collection will have its lazy loaded properties read, but the context in which this list was assembled doesn't exist anymore.

Making the `Appointment` class properties not virtual (lazy) is not an option here.

How can I make the lazy properties be loaded in the LINQ query?

**What I've tried**

I tried writing an AppointmentDTO class with the properties I need from Appointment and writing this LINQ:

```
from stf in staff
select new StaffDTO
{
    Appointments = stf.StaffAppointments.Select(a => new AppointmentDTO(a))
};
```

but then I get the parameterless constructor exception.

I also tried writing an implicit operator to cast Appointment to AppointmentDTO, but I got the cast exception from linq again.

Comment: have you tried eagerly loading using the `.Include` method?

Comment: I tried to use ctx.Set<Staff>().Include() but the method only accepts strings, and the examples I found all use properties: .Include(a => a.X) etc... Writing .Include("Staff.StaffAppointments").Include("Appointment.ServiceId").Include("...") cannot be the only way

Comment: Also, I dont need the lazy properties in this particular case. If I could just ignore them when serializint it would work too. But I cant use JsonIgnore because I dont want them to ALWAYS be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `ToList` your `stf.StaffAppointments`. Items in an `IEnumerable` are lazily produced, which means somewhere down the line when someone tries to iterate the DTO's `Appointments`, it requires the EF context to be active.

Unless you can tie the lifetime of the DTO to the lifetime of the context (which is awkward and unnecessary), you should just pull all the data from EF at the point where you're instantiating the DTO.

EDIT: I missed the fact that you had lazy loaded references to other entities in the Appointment entity. The problem right now is really that your StaffDTO isn't actually a DTO. A DTO is supposed to be a static (preferably serializable) snapshot all of the data present in a particular entity. You need to *copy* out all of the data, rather than just referencing the original entities. You can write it manually, or you can use something like AutoMapper to make things a bit easier.

Comment: Simply adding .ToList() doesn't make the lazy properties be loaded, which will still cause "Error getting value from 'XXXX' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Appointment_6FBEEBE6E2FBDE062AAA5202A2A79A3EEB432F7ABF40234BFDE4691384D07377".
The problem is that the Appointment object only exists inside the LINQ query, I cant access it after I called .ToList() on the query, AND THEN populate the Appointment list for each staff returned. I don't see an easy way out of this, or pretty for that matter

Comment: @victor I missed the the virtual properties. You need to eagerly load those as well, by using `.Include`.

Comment: @victor The problem right now is really that your StaffDTO isn't actually a DTO. A DTO is supposed to be a static snapshot all of the data present in a particular entity. You need to *copy* out all of the data, rather than just referencing the original entities.

Comment: I couldn't make include work. I thought about using it too. Maybe if you provide an example I can try. I tried to use it when getting the staff set.
It not a DTO because of the appointment lazy properties. If only I could make linq load them, everything would work
So I guess the question is: how to make appointments eager load inside the linq...

Comment: @victor The `.Include` would work by doing `ctx.Set<Staff>().Include(stf => stf.StaffAppointments.Select(app => app.Client)).Include(stf => stf.StaffAppointments.Select(app => app.Staff))` etc. etc.

Comment: @victor But again, the proper solution to the problem is to turn your "DTO" into an actual DTO. This means all of the data in the entities must be *copied* and stored in the actual DTO, rather than the DTO referencing the original entities.

Comment: I dont need the lazy properties in this particular case. If I could just ignore them when serializint it would work too. But I cant use JsonIgnore because I dont want them to ALWAYS be ignored.

Comment: @victor You can create a custom configuration object for every serialization in most libraries (I remember you can do this for JSON.NET at least). This obviates the need for any serialization attributes. Alternatively, make an `AppointmentDTO` class that can hold the data you *do* need, copy the relevant data from each `Appointment` into an `AppointmentDTO`, and make `StaffDTO.Appointments` an `IReadOnlyCollection<AppointmentDTO>`.

Comment: I cant create AppointmentDTO from each Appointment inside the linq (as I stated in my question near the bottom). To do it I would have to load the appointments separately and them map the appointments to each staff, while inside the linq I already have that. It just loading the same thing twice. There must be a better more efficient way

Comment: @victor Wait, what parameterless constructor exception? For your JSON serialization?

Comment: Inside the linq query: from s in staff select new StaffDTO { Appointments = stf.StaffAppointments.Select(a => new AppointmentDTO(a)) }; This throws Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @victor Weird, we don't actually want LINQ to entities there. Just `ToList` it first: `... new StaffDTO { Appointments = stf.StaffAppointments.ToList().Select(a => new AppointmentDTO(a)) }`.

Comment: Doesnt work either. Same exception. Even tried implicit operator and casting. Unable to cast the type 'MVC.Models.Appointment' to type 'MVC.Models.ViewModels.AppointmentDTO'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Easiest thing to do is to have 2 properties in my dto, one for the Appointments and one for AppointmentsDto, then I can perform the mapping after I materialize the query.

Comment: @victor You can't cast `Appointment` to an `AppointmentDTO`, since one has no relation to the other in the type hierarchy. I think maybe the `ToList` is needed further up. Try doing `from stf in staff.ToList()`.

Comment: The cast is valid, I just cant cast there in the linq. I think there is no good solution to this. EF 6 lacks so much.. I could have done this with laravel in 2 lines :/

Comment: @victor How would the cast be valid? Appointment does not derive from AppointmentDTO (or at least it shouldn't), so you can't cast one to the other. Regarding "no good solution to this", did you try `staff.ToList()`? The problem you're having is that your `Select` is being called on the wrong `IEnumerable` implementation, specifically one that is tied to Entity Framework. This `IEnumerable` implementation doesn't work like regular in memory lists or collections or whatever: instead, it takes your lambda expressions and tries to build an SQL query out of them, which is not what you want here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114284/discussion-between-victor-and-asad-saeeduddin).

Answer (score 0):

Change that to `Appointments = stf.StaffAppointments.ToList()` to materialize those objects immediately.

Comment: This does not solve the problem: Error getting value from 'XXX' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Appointment_6FBEEBE6E2FBDE062AAA5202A2A79A3EEB432F7ABF40234BFDE4691384D07377', as I said.